# jQuery slideToggel and scroll to bottom

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

In this example I am trying to slideToggel a part of the footer and also scroll to the bottom of the page and change the img to up.png. How do I add those 2 added funcationality to the slideToggle.

**HTML**

```
<li id="show_footer"><a><img src="images/footer/down.png" /></a></li>

<nav id="sub">
</nav>
```

**CSS**

```
nav#sub {
display: none;
}
```

**SCRIPT**

```
$("#show_footer").click(function() {
 $("#sub").slideToggle("slow");
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this code,

```
$("#show_footer").click(function() {
 $("#sub").slideToggle("slow");
$("html, body").animate({ scrollTop: $(document).height() }, "slow");
    if($('#sub:visible').length > 0){
        $('#show_footer > a > img').attr('src', 'new/src/file/up.png');
    }else{
    $('#show_footer > a > img').attr('src', 'new/src/file/down.png');
    }
});
```

This should do the trick. Edited because smooth scroll. **THIS IS NOT TESTED.**

Comment: the page has to scroll to bottom and the image has to change when the user clicks on the #show_footer and the #sub is slided. Maybe a callback function?

Comment: ok got it but the scolling is sudden with no animation. Anyway to control that?

Comment: edited. As i wrote: Not tested, but i think this works - if not - You can edit this. Maybe this helps you to get the solution.

Comment: this works but the scrolling only starts when the slideToggle is finished. How do I chain it? - $("html, body").animate({ scrollTop: $(document).height()-$(window).height() });